# Can fiat money like USD be transferred via smart contracts in Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am studying about Ethereum smart contracts and how they are being used to transfer tokens. I would appreciate it if you could provide a clarification on the below issue.

Suppose User A needs to send some amount of USDs ( or any fiat money ) to User B. Can this use case be resolved using smart contracts in Ethereum? I understand that tokens can be transferred instead of fiat money, but is there a way to include fiat money as well in a smart contract?

Thank you.

Comment: No. But you can create a token that represent fiat money, but someone will have to guarantee the parity, for example a Central Bank. Other cryptocoins have done something similar search for USDT to find more.

Answer (score 1):

No you have to use an exchange coinbase or Kraken. If you want a distributed exchange you can use via a smart contract you can use something like CoinDesk, however its NOT going to allow you interact with Fiat, you can trade like Ethereum for bitcoin. This will likely never be possible with Fiat since most exchanges require you to know your customer so its always going to require a third party intermideary

Answer (score 0):

No, currently there is no way to include fiat money in a smart contract.